# how to handle the error page? Docsify loading forever

Tags: docsify

I don't see there is any timeout if loading failed, does anyone knows?

Here is my sample page for infinity loading: https://dotku.us/r/#404

Answer (score 0):

you can see https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=notfoundpage.

But I noticed you set `notFoundPage: false`, what effect are you trying to achieve?